# Change Text Color with Switch/Toggle Css/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Thank you for reading this question**

- Actually, I am trying to create a login form for student and teachers
- Where there is a Switch/toggle button between Teacher and Student text
- I want to change the colour (let say to grey from green) of the text when the switch toggle to respective(teacher/student)
- For Example, if I pressed the switch and the toggle ball sift to right means the Student text will be grey and the same for the opposite side

**Here is my code**
**index.html**

```css
.form-container{
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            padding: 30px 10px 30px 10px;
            margin: 0% 5% 0% 5%;
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: green;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);
            -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);
        }
        .input-design{
            margin: 0% 15% 0% 15%;
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
        .input-design input[type=text]{
            height: 50px;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        .input-design input[type=password]{
            height: 50px;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        .button-design{
            padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
            height: 50px;
            font-weight: 600;
            font-size: 20px;
            margin: 5% 15% 5% 15%;
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
            border:1px solid white;
        }
        .button-design:hover{

            border:1px solid green;
            background-color: white;
            color: green;
        }

        .switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="form-container">
            <div class="role-selector">
                Teacher
                <label class="switch">
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <span class="slider round"></span>
                      </label>
                Student
            </div>
            <div class="input-design">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="button-design">
                Login
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to revise your HTML, then this CSS-only solution is also possible:

```css
/* CSS Additions */

/* Checkbox does not need to be displayed */
input {
  display: none;
}

/* Color labels green by default */
.role-selector input+span {
  color: green;
}
.role-selector input+*+*+span {
  color: grey;
}


/* Color labels when input is checked */
.role-selector input:checked+span {
  color: grey;
}
.role-selector input:checked+*+*+span {
  color: green;
}

/* --- */

.form-container {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 30px 10px 30px 10px;
  margin: 0% 5% 0% 5%;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: green;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
}

.input-design {
  margin: 0% 15% 0% 15%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.input-design input[type=text] {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.input-design input[type=password] {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.button-design {
  padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 5% 15% 5% 15%;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.button-design:hover {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: white;
  color: green;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}



/*
Remove:
.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
*/

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}



input:checked+span+.switch .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+span+.switch .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+span+.switch .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="form-container">
    <div class="role-selector">
      <!-- Move input outside of .switch label -->
      <input type="checkbox" checked id="role-checkbox">
      <span>Teacher</span>
      <!-- Add for attribute that matches id of check input -->
      <label class="switch" for="role-checkbox">
                  <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>
      <span>Student</span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-design">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="button-design">
      Login
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dacre Denny Sir for helping me with your proper code and more user friendly

Answer (score 0):

You should toggle the class of parent's div when input is changed, and then set the color with that class name.

```js
document.getElementById('switch').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.target.parentElement.parentElement.classList.toggle('student');
});
```

```css
.form-container{
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            padding: 30px 10px 30px 10px;
            margin: 0% 5% 0% 5%;
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: green;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);
            -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);
        }
        .input-design{
            margin: 0% 15% 0% 15%;
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
        .input-design input[type=text]{
            height: 50px;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        .input-design input[type=password]{
            height: 50px;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        .button-design{
            padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
            height: 50px;
            font-weight: 600;
            font-size: 20px;
            margin: 5% 15% 5% 15%;
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
            border:1px solid white;
        }
        .button-design:hover{

            border:1px solid green;
            background-color: white;
            color: green;
        }

        .switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.role-selector {
  color: green;
}
 
.role-selector.student {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="form-container">
            <div class="role-selector">
                Teacher
                <label class="switch">
                        <input id="switch" type="checkbox">
                        <span class="slider round"></span>
                      </label>
                Student
            </div>
            <div class="input-design">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="button-design">
                Login
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually put the word **Teacher and Student** inside the **`span`** element and give it an Id. And assign an **ID to input switch** to bind with a **`js function`** in **`onclick event`**.

```css
.form-container{
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            padding: 30px 10px 30px 10px;
            margin: 0% 5% 0% 5%;
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: green;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);
            -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);
        }
        .input-design{
            margin: 0% 15% 0% 15%;
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
        .input-design input[type=text]{
            height: 50px;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        .input-design input[type=password]{
            height: 50px;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        .button-design{
            padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
            height: 50px;
            font-weight: 600;
            font-size: 20px;
            margin: 5% 15% 5% 15%;
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
            border:1px solid white;
        }
        .button-design:hover{

            border:1px solid green;
            background-color: white;
            color: green;
        }

        .switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
        <div class="form-container">
            <div class="role-selector">
                <span class="" id="teacher">Teacher</span>
                <label class="switch">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" onclick="checkYesNo()">
                        <span class="slider round"></span>
                      </label>
                <span class="" id="student">Student</span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-design">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="button-design">
                Login
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    
    <script>
    function checkYesNo() {
        if (document.getElementById('toggle').checked) {
            document.getElementById('student').style.color = 'grey';
            document.getElementById('teacher').style.color = 'green';
        }else {
           document.getElementById('teacher').style.color = 'grey';
           document.getElementById('student').style.color = 'green';
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much fmsthird Sir for helping me with your proper code

Answer (score 0):

Making use of before and after elements instead of text. Updated css at the bottom of css code. No jquery needed.

```css
.form-container{
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            padding: 30px 10px 30px 10px;
            margin: 0% 5% 0% 5%;
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: green;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);
            -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);
        }
        .input-design{
            margin: 0% 15% 0% 15%;
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
        .input-design input[type=text]{
            height: 50px;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        .input-design input[type=password]{
            height: 50px;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        .button-design{
            padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
            height: 50px;
            font-weight: 600;
            font-size: 20px;
            margin: 5% 15% 5% 15%;
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
            border:1px solid white;
        }
        .button-design:hover{

            border:1px solid green;
            background-color: white;
            color: green;
        }

        .switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* Input must be visible for before and after elements. Relative used for absolute position of children */

.switch input {
  position: relative;
}

/* Set text on before and after elements */

input::before,
input::after {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
}

input::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  content: 'student';
}

input::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  content: 'teacher';
}

/* Change colors based on checked status */

input:checked::before {
  color: green;
}

input:checked::after {
  color: grey;
}

input:not(:checked)::before {
  color: grey;
}

input:not(:checked)::after {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="form-container">
            <div class="role-selector">
                <label class="switch">
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <span class="slider round"></span>
                      </label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-design">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="button-design">
                Login
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question but your output is different please scroll down to see fmsthird, Dacre Denny